# JSP tags in a Freemarker template

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker

I want to use some custom tags in a freemarker template which is easy enough as I can include the JspSupportServlet in my web.xml file and include the folowing line in the template.

```
<#assign my=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/mytaglib.tld"] />
```

However how do I go about doing this if the .tld is bundled in a JAR file inside the META-INF directory? I tried both of these with no luck.

```
<#assign my=JspTaglibs["/META-INF/mytaglib.tld"] />
<#assign my=JspTaglibs["/mynamespace"] />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeMarker automatically scans all JAR files in your WEB-INF/lib directory. If it finds .tld files inside a JAR's META-INF directory, like your META-INF/mytaglib.tld, it will peek inside it in order to find the  `<uri>` tag. If it finds one, it will make the taglib available via this URI, e.g a taglib defined like

```
<taglib>
  <shortname>my custom taglib</shortname>
  <uri>http://example.org/mytaglib</uri>
  <!-- ... -->
</taglib>
```

can be used in FreeMarker via

```
<#assign my=JspTaglibs["http://example.org/mytaglib"] />
```

At least this worked for me...

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had already tried using the URI however the it didn't include the http://hostname and it seems freemarker only recognises full http urls as namespaces. So I have changed the namespace to be http://hostname/mynamespace and it works perfectly.